# SoapSerializationEnvelope error

Tags: java, android, magento, soap, android-ksoap2

I am new to Magento SOAP api  , and i am just fetching the session ID by giving the correct user name and API key in my android application . But i am getting the error in this following line .

```
            androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
```

I have given Internet Permission to my android code and this is the code i am trying with . and I am using KSoap2 android external JAR file and I have added it to my build path .

Please help me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:Magento";
private static final String URL = "http://127.0.0.1/index.php/api/v2_soap/";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        env.dotNet = false;
        env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
        env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "login");
        request.addProperty("username", "cats");
        request.addProperty("apiKey", "sudhir123");
        env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
        Object result = env.getResponse();
        Log.d("sessionId", result.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

and this is my logcat

```
09-03 00:49:08.455  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-03 00:49:08.456  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at    android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
09-03 00:49:08.456  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
09-03 00:49:08.456  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:154)
09-03 00:49:08.456  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
09-03 00:49:08.456  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
09-03 00:49:08.456  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
09-03 00:49:08.456  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
09-03 00:49:08.456  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:174)
09-03 00:49:08.456  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
09-03 00:49:08.456  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
09-03 00:49:08.456  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.openOutputStream(ServiceConnectionSE.java:130)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.sendData(HttpTransportSE.java:292)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:184)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
09-03 00:49:08.457  13505-13505/sportee.sudhir.inchoosoap W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Post your log cat...

Comment: Sir I have posted now . Error is at this line  androidHttpTransport.call("", env);

Comment: You are missing the SOAP action when you call `androidHttpTransport.call("", env);`  What SOAP action are you intending to use?

Comment: Sir I am just displaying the session id ..I have to get confirmation about the SOAP api means whether it is working in my code or not